# jQuery jsonp: skip actually executing the jsonp?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to use jQuery to check if a certain website/port is blocked/unblocked by a user's computer. I can get it to work properly, with a small annoyance that it throws errors e.g. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "

Is there anyway to simply let jQuery do a get request on the page to see the return code, but not actually inject it into the website as javascript? If not, will there ever be any side effects from this code?

Note: I do not own the site(s) to be checked, so I cannot make them implement jsonp.

```
var checkPorts = function() {
    var url = "__redacted__" ;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "get",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'jsonp', // it is for supporting crossdomain
        crossDomain : true,
        asynchronous : false,
        timeout : 5000, // set a timeout in milliseconds
        complete : function(xhr, responseText, thrownError) {
            if(xhr.status == "200") {
                //nothing
            }
            else {
                $("#ports-warning").slideDown();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: You cannot do this with JSONP, since it's not a normal Ajax request. JSONP is just inserting a `script` tag and that process leads the browser to load whatever the URL points to (and evaluate it as JavaScript). But getting the syntax error means that the call was successful... although this does not seem to be a very reliable technique.

Comment: But how does the "complete" function know whether or not the script/page was loaded correctly? Would there be a way to inject a webpage as a script not of type javascript, but as type text or something that didnt actually execute the page?

Comment: I was playing a bit with the `script` element, but it looks like whenever you set the `type` property to something that doesn't trigger script execution (e.g. `text/plain`), then the content pointed to by `src` is not even loaded. So no, there does not seem to be a way, with `script` at least. You might be able to use an `iframe` element and listen to it's `load` event. http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element. (that's how jQuery's `complete` callback works, only that it inserts a `script` element).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `asynchronous` property of `$.ajax`, did you mean `async`? Look in the browser's debugger and see how the request is being made, it would have to be XHR for your approach to have any chance of working. Also if you are using jQuery 1.9.x try it with the jQuery Migrate plugin.